# Intel XDK FourSquares API key and Secret

Tags: intel-xdk

I am attempting to use foursquares as a plugin for my application in Intel Xdk. It was I need to enter a API key and Shared Secret. I have then followed the link to the foursquares web site but can find either of these. Has anyone any idea where I gain these credentials

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the XDK, under where it says "API Key" and "Shared Secret" there is a link to follow ("Sign up").  This should take you to https://developer.foursquare.com

When you go there, you'll see a "get started" button.  Click on that and follow the instructions to set up an API key, in particular near the top of the page it says:

> Before you get started, you should create an app on Foursquare. This
>   will give you a client ID and client secret which are needed for using
>   the API.

Click on "Create an app" and follow those instructions.  You'll need an account, but I don't know what other requirements because I didn't go past that.

Remember your API Key and Share Secret will be unique to you.  Most services require this, the better to track usage and such.